# Write a program in C that prompts the user to enter two dates and then indicates which date comes earlier on the calendar

Tags: c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
    
    
int main(void)
{
    int month, day, year, month_2, day_2, year_2;
    printf("Enter first date (mm/dd/yy): ");
    scanf("%d/%d/%d", &month, &day, &year);

    printf("Enter second date (mm/dd/yy): ");
    scanf("%d/%d/%d", &month_2, &day_2, &year_2);

    if (year < year_2 && month < month_2 && day < day_2)
        printf("%d/%d/%d is earlier than %d/%d/%d\n", month, day, year, month_2, day_2, year_2);

    else if (year == year_2 && month == month_2 && day == day_2)
        printf("%d/%d/%d is earlier than %d/%d/%d\n", month, day, year, month_2, day_2, year_2);
    else
        printf("%d/%d/%d is earlier than %d/%d/%d\n", month, day, year, month_2, day_2, year_2);

}
```

I get an output of 3/6/8 is earlier than 5/17/7 which is false.
I'm completely stuck on this problem and would really appreciate your help.
I am using K N King's
[C Programming: A Modern Approach, 2nd Edn](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/0393979504/) 2008.

Comment: (a) Every one of your `printf` statements says the first date is earlier than the second date. (b) Those comparisons cannot distinguish which date is earlier. You need to compare the year first. If it is the same, then you need to compare the month. If it is the same, then you need to compare the day of the month.

Comment: You should check that the `scanf()` calls both return 3 (since three values are read by each). However, that doesn't affect your problem. You should probably also check the dates for validity (negative numbers, zeros, numbers in the millions or billions are all accepted by your code), but again that isn't your main problem. Your comparisons are faulty. If the years are different, you can order the dates; if the years are the same but the months are different, you can order the dates; if the years and months are the same, the day of the month orders the dates. Write a function to compare dates.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of the program looks correct but logic doesn't. To Compare dates, First proceed with years, If they are equal then proceed to months, Is still they are equal, Compare days.

So, You have to modify conditions slightly. The following code serves the conditions part of your code.

By the way, your printf() function is also incorrect, You have always been printing the first date is earlier than second.

```
if (year < year_2)
        printf("%d/%d/%d is earlier than %d/%d/%d\n", month, day, year, month_2, day_2, year_2);
    else if (year == year_2)
        if (month < month_2)
            printf("%d/%d/%d is earlier than %d/%d/%d\n", month, day, year, month_2, day_2, year_2);
        else if (month == month_2)
            if (day < day_2)
                printf("%d/%d/%d is earlier than %d/%d/%d\n", month, day, year, month_2, day_2, year_2);
            else if (day == day_2)
                printf("%d/%d/%d is equal to %d/%d/%d\n", month_2, day_2, year_2, month, day, year);
            else
                printf("%d/%d/%d is earlier than %d/%d/%d\n", month_2, day_2, year_2, month, day, year);            
        else
            printf("%d/%d/%d is earlier than %d/%d/%d\n", month_2, day_2, year_2, month, day, year);
    else
        printf("%d/%d/%d is earlier than %d/%d/%d\n", month_2, day_2, year_2, month, day, year);
```